# Understand spread and destructure use in the following reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to wrap my head around how this reducer works so I can add a REMOVE_ITEM to my action handlers. My current try gives a state.filter is not a function error.

```
// ------------------------------------
// Action Handlers
// ------------------------------------
const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [GET_POSTS]: (state, action) => ({ ...state, ...action.payload}),
  [PICK_ITEM]: (state, action) => ({ ...state, ...action.payload}),
  [REMOVE_ITEM]: (state, action) => ({...state.filter(item => item !== action.payload)}) // <-- NOT WORKING
}

// ------------------------------------
// Reducer
// ------------------------------------
const initialState = []
export default function contentReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type]

  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
}
```

I'm not quite sure about what's done with the spread and the destructure there. If I understand correctly the spread gives us a copied version of the state so we're not mutating it, but how is the following: `handler(state, action)` creates our new state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each action, `[GET_POSTS]` for example, is spreading `state` and the `action.payload` and returning the resulting value;

Yes, the `{...state` bit spreads all the properties of `state` into a new object.

This syntax is *also* like `Object.assign` or `_.merge` in that parameters to the right merge with the existing parameters to the left (over-writing if they are the same property.

Maybe if we produce a manual expansion this will make more sense.

**With these:**

```
const state = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const action = { payload: { c: 4 }};
```

**So this:**

```
{ ...state, ...action.payload}
```

**expands to:**

```
{ ...{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, ...{ c: 4 }}
```

**and from the left spreads first to:**

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, ...{ c: 4 }}
```

**and then `c` is overwritten making:**

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 4 }
```

Hope that helps.